# Webpack dependency is requiring relative path

Tags: webpack, blueimp

I installed `blueimp-bootstrap-image-gallery` via npm and am trying to require it with webpack. However, the plugin is declaring it's dependencies like so:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([
      'jquery',
      './blueimp-gallery'
    ], factory)
  }
```

So it's requiring `./blueimp-gallery`, which does not exist. If it would require just `blueimp-gallery`, it would work. Is there any way to override/shim/alias this dependency? I tried adding

```
'./blueimp-gallery': 'blueimp-gallery/js/blueimp-gallery'
```

as a `resolve.alias`, but that doesn't work.

For the time being I used the import-loader to disable `define` so the plugin exposes itself to global scope, then used export-loader to actually export the vars. But I really don't want these two external dependencies just for the one module.

Comment: Hi Chris, did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Hey. No, at least not the way I wanted to. But here's how I solved it using the import loader: [link](https://gist.github.com/chlab/fe7b8b4116fe79121035107be7e8b2ad).